# How to construct SQL query to select chat participants

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables. Users(id, fullname), Chats(id, name) and Chats_Participants(chatId, userId). I need to select all the chats in which user with specified id consists. For example:

Chats:
1. 1, 'Test'

Users:
 1. 1, 'Test user'
 2. 2, 'Test user2'

Chat_Participants:
 1. 1(chatId), 1(userId)
 2. 1(chatId), 2(userId)

As a result, I need something like this:
1(chatId) 'Test'(chatName) participants(array of users in chat)

First I've wrote this:

```
select chats.*, json_agg(users) as participants
    from chats
           inner join chats_participants c2 on chats.id = c2."chatId"
           inner join users on c2."userId" = users.id
    where users.id = $userId
    group by chats.id;
```

but this query selects only one participant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with array_agg in postgresql. Demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=0dc5232aa81846c85e4c138fb95c6235). Users table is not linked here, printing user id from chat_participants table instead.

```
SELECT chats.chat_id,chats.name, array_agg(userid order by chats.chat_id) 
FROM chats 
INNER JOIN chat_participants ON chats.chat_id = chat_participants.chat_id
GROUP BY chats.chat_id,chats.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
SELECT c.chat_id, c.name,
       array_agg(cp.userid order by cp.user_id) as users
FROM chats c INNER JOIN
     chat_participants cp
     ON c.chat_id = cp.chat_id
GROUP BY c.chat_id, c.name
HAVING SUM( (cp.userid = $userid)::int ) > 0;
```

This returns only chats that have your user of interest.